# загадочное исчезновение письма exim4|dovecot

Tags: ubuntu, email, dovecot, exim4

На локальном сервере(работает на Ubuntu 18.04.6) установлен exim4 и dovecot, для работы почтового сервера, но очень редко отправленные письма просто не доходят до адресата даже если это было в рамках локального почтового сервера или отправлены даже самому себе, в логах exim4 всё хорошо пишет что всё отправлено и получено, но на почту письмо не пришло.
единственная проблема что есть ошибка `no host name found for IP address` но она и до этого изредка появляется но письма доходят, вот кусок лога когда отправлял с почты 1@test.ru на почту 2@test.ru ,но письмо не пришло и есть в отправленных у 1@test.ru

```
2023-11-22 11:25:21 no host name found for IP address 000
2023-11-22 11:25:21 Accepted from 1@test.ru to 2@test.ru by whitelist.
2023-11-22 11:25:21 1r5iXx-0005UQ-EV <= 1@test.ru H=([10.0.0.12]) [000] P=esmtpa A=auth_plain:1@test.ru S=66344 id=e75ea6dd-c72c-418b-@test.ru from <1@test.ru> for 2@test.ru
2023-11-22 11:25:22 1r5iXx-0005UQ-EV => 2<2@test.ru> R=procmail T=dovecot_deliver_pipe
2023-11-22 11:25:22 1r5iXx-0005UQ-EV Completed
```

Куда копать и в чём может быть проблема?
В интернете ничего подобного не нашёл